# Update event in Google Calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to update a field (the date_time) on an event object by using the Ruby wrapper for Google's Calendar API. [Source here](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/generated/google/apis/calendar_v3/service.rb#L1645).

The [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google%2FApis%2FCalendarV3%2FCalendarService:update_event) has this information on the method:

```
update_event(calendar_id, event_id, event_object = nil, always_include_email: nil, max_attendees: nil, send_notifications: nil, supports_attachments: nil, fields: nil, quota_user: nil, user_ip: nil, options: nil)
```

I don't understand the third argument - should I instantiate a new event object with updated fields? Tried that but just getting an error response and "Invalid request".

Any hint how to go forward would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[Found an example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update#examples):

```
event = client.get_event('primary', 'eventId')
event.summary = 'Appointment at Somewhere'
result = client.update_event('primary', event.id, event)
print result.updated
```